# Testing rails API for sign-up with devise. Error: "Missing 'confirm_success_url' parameter."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, authentication, devise

I am trying to use [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) and [devise_token_auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth) for authentication in my app.

I am overriding the registration controller as follow:

```
module Overrides
  class RegistrationsController < DeviseTokenAuth::RegistrationsController

    ## I am doing these to go around the `Can't verify CSRF token authenticity` Error.
    # skip_before_action :valid_authenticity_token, only: :create
    protect_from_forgery :except => :create


    def sign_up_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :name, :nickname)
    end

  end
end
```

I am also sending in my parameters using [swagger docs api](https://github.com/richhollis/swagger-docs) as follow:

```
swagger_api :create do
  summary "Sign up a new user"
  param :form, "user[email]", :string, :required, "Email of the new user"
  param :form, "user[password]", :string, :required, "Password of the new user"
  param :form, "user[password_confirmation]", :string, :required, "Retype Password of the new user"
  param :form, "user[name]", :string, :optional, "Name of the new user"
  param :form, "user[nickname]", :string, :optional, "Nick-Name of the new user"
  response :not_acceptable
  response :success
end
```

This produces parameters on my terminal as follow:

```
Processing by Overrides::RegistrationsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"user"=>{"email"=>"sadf@fsd.fgs", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "name"=>"rgefsrfgrfdfsd", "nickname"=>"rgefsrfgrfdfsd"}}
```

However, this request never hits my model, ( talkless of creating the new user ). On the page, however, I am having the following error:

[image: Screen shot of the error response.]

And a `Completed 403 Forbidden in 93ms (Views: 0.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)` on the terminal.

How can I go about solving this? Thanks

**Update:**

```
#route.rb: 
namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do


      mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth', controllers: {
                                          confirmations:      'overrides/confirmations',
                                          passwords:          'overrides/passwords',
                                          registrations:      'overrides/registrations',
                                          sessions:           'overrides/sessions',
                                        }
      ...

    end
  end


#Countroller:
class ApiController < ApplicationController
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::SetUserByToken
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
end

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session, if: Proc.new { |c| c.request.format == 'application/json' }
end

#user.rb:
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules.
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
          :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
          :confirmable, :omniauthable
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User
```

Comment: share your `routes` and full `application_controller.rb` if not solved yet

Comment: Related issue https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/issues/241

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `confirm_success_url` param is used to support multiple client applications. If the param isn't required, then the API has no way of knowing where to redirect after email confirmation.

But for your `devise_token_auth`, your `application_controller.rb` should be:

```
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::SetUserByToken
```

In your **routes.rb**

`mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth'`

Remove the `confirmable` tag In **user.rb** , so that it looks like below

```
 devise :database_authenticatable, :recoverable,
         :trackable, :validatable, :registerable,
         :omniauthable

  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User
```

Comment: Oh yes, I have the above two in their respective places. But are you saying that assuming this is being consumed from a real client ( say a mobile phone application for example ) this `confirm_success_url` will not be an issue?

Comment: @kindly update your application_controller.rb and routes.rb so that i can see more

Comment: Just did that in the question. Kindly check above. thanks

Comment: Oh yes, I had that too. I've added it to the question post. kindly check. #sigh

Comment: @SunnyK confirmable flag is not in my user.rb (which i pasted) , you'll have that , remove that

Comment: Hmmm... It worked. thanks. Can you tell me why the confirmable flag was causing this error?

Comment: for the same reason as in answer , for more details check devise docs

Comment: What if I need to use `confirmable`?

Answer (score 9):

The solution is just to set the default URL in `config/initializer/devise_token_auth.rb`:

```
DeviseTokenAuth.setup do |config|
    config.default_confirm_success_url = "confirmed"
end
```

Answer (score 6):

As a note to anyone who might find this, if you have

```
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User
```

*before* your `devise` section in `user.rb`, devise_token_auth will [include a list of modules](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/blob/18d7d67947be2e9c038910246e0018460cac6d41/app/models/devise_token_auth/concerns/user.rb#L19-L24) for you, which includes `confirmable` in the list (and may generate the above error).  Just move the module include *after* the devise section and it'll work.

This is not the problem the OP had, but it's how I got here.

Comment: that is help me a lot,, thanks. Not sure why the generator bring own devise module..